# Create a function taking a vector and list and returning the product of each element of them

Tags: r

I want to create a function `f` in `R` which takes a list `x` and a vector `y` as its arguments and returns a list whose elements are products after multiplying each element of the vector by each element of the list.

```
x = list(x1 = runif(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = 1:10, x4 = seq(1,.1,-.1))
y = c(2, 1, 3)
```

I want `f(x,y)` to return a list whose elements are `x[[i]] * y[j]` for each `i = 1:length(x)`
and `j = 1:length(y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
lapply(x, function(z) lapply(y, "*", z))
```

However you need to do a bit of work on moving things around with indexing as right now you're bordering on let me order up a function and you guys make it for me.

Comment: I am a new R user. I could see this code works but I find it hard to call elements of the resulting list for further analysis.

Comment: Have you read the intro manual that talks about indexing? http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html `[[`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mapply("*", x, y)`, but you need to modify "y" so that each multiplier is repeated `length(x)` times. In other words, the following should work:

```
mapply("*", x, rep(y, each = length(x)))
```

You may need to add names back in to the results.

---

If the length of each list item is the same (in your example, they all contain 10 values), the following is a variation on @Tyler's answer:

```
lapply(y, "*", do.call(rbind, x))
```

This will result in a list of matrices of the results.

Comment: I found the output of mapply easier to use. I would prefer naming the elements in a way I can identify which one's belong to what. This could be using the prefix x

Comment: as `d = lapply(x, function(z){sapply(y, "*", z)})' and `df = as.data.frame(d)'

Answer (score 1):

This should also work - depend on what form of outcome you prefer

```
lapply(x , outer , y)
```